# Show $\bigcup _{n=.5(b-a)} ^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n] = (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show $$\bigcup _{n=0.5(b-a)} ^{\infty}\left[a+\frac1n, b-\frac1n\right] = (a,b)$$

I got that the LHS is a subset of the RHS, but I can't figure out how to show that the RHS is a subset of the LHS.  I assume you have to do this by contradiction (assume $\exists x \in (a,b) : x \notin \bigcup _{n=.5(b-a)} ^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n]$) but I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If $x\in (a,b)$  then 
$$x=a+\frac{1}{1/(x-a)}=b-\frac{1}{1/(b-x)}.$$
Therefore, if $n\geq \max\left(1/(x-a),1/(b-x)\right)$ then
$$a+\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq b-\frac{1}{n}.$$